# Rescale a vector to a specific average in r

Tags: r

I have a simple vector, for instance :

```
a <- c(-1.02, 2.25, 9.12, -2.09, 0.02)
```

I need to rescale it to an average of 100. But I really don't find the solution in order to solve my problem...
I tried with scale() function in order to rescale the values but however we cannot specify the mean.

I want to have in output when i calculate the mean of the vector : > 100

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: I want to have in output when i calculate the mean of the vector : `> 100`

Comment: If you can update your post with the expected values, it would be good for crosschecking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scale` scales to a mean value of 0, keeping the standard error or scaling it to unity. So just add the desired mean to `scale(a)` to get a vector with the new mean

```
b1 <- c(scale(a)) + 100
mean(b1)
#[1] 100
b1
#[1]  99.40138 100.13288 101.66969  99.16202  99.63403

b2 <- c(scale(a, scale = FALSE)) + 100
mean(b2)
#[1] 100
b2
#[1]  97.324 100.594 107.464  96.254  98.364
```

Note that `b2` is equal to

```
a - mean(a) + 100
#[1]  97.324 100.594 107.464  96.254  98.364
```

Comment: Both of solution are quiet good thanks a lot !

Answer (score 4):

What about:

```
rescaled <- a/mean(a)*100

rescaled
[1]  -61.594203  135.869565  550.724638 -126.207729    1.207729

mean(rescaled)
[1] 100
```

Comment: It's exactly what I want, thanks you very much! Have a good day!

Answer (score 2):

We can use

```
library(scales)
rescale(a, to = c(0, mean(a))) * 100
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can use `scale` like below

```
scale(a) + 100
```